# Why do we repeat the value in _id field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb so I am not sure what is the best practice. But I have seen many times the value in _id field is repeated.

```
db.memberrecords.find().limit(2).forEach(printjson)
{
        "_id" : "999783",
        "Memberid" : "999783",
        "Name" : "ASHEESH SHARMA",
        "Gender" : "M",
}
{
        "_id" : "999784",
        "Memberid" : "999784",
        "Name" : "Sanwal Singh Meena",
        "Gender" : "M",
}
```

For example here _id and Memberid does the same thing and store the same value

Is there any reason why we do so ? why do we have two fields that store the same result?

Comment: No inherent reason to do so, that’s a redundancy in your specific system.

Answer (score 1):

So going with the basics first

- `_id` is default id (primary key if you are coming from SQL) for mongoDB documents.
- By default `_id` is of type `ObjectId`
- It is possible to change type of `_id`
- `_id` is always required for document, if its not there, it is automatically generated.

So coming back to question, why duplicated values. It totally depends on how you plan you document structure. Some prefer to got with auto generated `_id` as their primary key while others want to create and maintain it themselves or change its type.

In your case one possibility is that the creator wanted a meaningful key name and so they went with adding an extra field (memberId) to have whatever is in `_id` and since `_id` is required they end up maintaining both of these keys. It completely depends on creator and his opinion.

For more information on mongoDB documents, see this manual
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: So is this a good practice considering we are introducing a redundancy here?

Comment: If its only purpose is to store whatever is in `_id` this is not required and should not be created. Since your `_id` is also self maintained you now have the overhead of maintaining two keys.